# Measuring the similarity of two distributions

Tags: similarities, bhattacharyya

What is the recommended approach to measure the similarity between two distributions of a variable—discrete and continuous? Is [Bhattacharyya distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance)  a good measure?

Comment: There are [many ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance) to do this. The best method depends on your application.

Comment: What about Hellinger, Euclid, Manhatten, Canbera, ...? Try each one out, perform some evaluation (e.g. $k$-fold cross validation), observe the results and pick the metric with the highest result.